# Getting latest repository infos from Github Archive

Tags: github, google-bigquery, github-archive

I want to retrieve the latest infos about a repository using Google Big Query on the github archive timeline dataset.

I tried to join on max(created_at) but i get vastly incomplete informations. Here is the query for the rails repo :

```
SELECT *
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline] a
JOIN EACH
  (
     SELECT MAX(created_at) as max_created, repository_url
     FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
     GROUP EACH BY repository_url
  ) b
  ON 
  b.max_created = a.created_at and
  b.repository_url = a.repository_url
WHERE payload_ref_type="repository" AND a.repository_name = 'rails'
```

I know this dataset doesn't include data before 2011, but it should contain informations about recently active repositories

I don't understand the results of this query :

- It only return events of type 'CreateEvent', which are always older than 'PushEvent'
- It doesn't return the main rails repository : https://github.com/rails/rails
- Github search reports 147149 repositories with the name "rails", the query only return 476 repositories

Is my query false in some way, why don't it return PushEvents ?
Is there another trick about the github archive dataset ?

Comment: I think the reason for your missing data here may be that your filter (ref_type=repository and repository_name='rails') may not have a timestamp with the max_created timestamp. Try copying the filter into the other side of the join too.

Comment: I tried to add the same filter to the join : i get results 1146 results and it doesn't include the main rails repository. Pentium10 also suggested i ask you for help to solve the "Resource exceeded" error when i remove the filter on payload_ref_type="repository"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve the latest version of a row, you need to use [Window functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#windowfunctions).

You can get the order of the modifications based on the `created_at` timestamp column using.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT a.*,
          row_number() over (partition BY repository_url
                             ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS seq_num
   FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline] a
   WHERE payload_ref_type="repository"
     AND a.repository_name = 'rails') d
WHERE seq_num=1 LIMIT 10
```

`seq_num=1` means it will grab the first entry from that specific partition, and since we ordered descending that will be the most recent entry.

Keeping `payload_ref_type="repository` in the query would return only 1050 repos, but if you remove that part you will have more.

In the same style you could also leverage data from day and monthly events. Those are in separate table and can be used with table wildcard functions.

Comment: Thanks it's much better. If i remove the payload_ref_type="repository" constraint i get a "Ressource exceeded" error, i guess i comes from the order by but i don't see how to remove it... Do you see another way to get more results from this query ?

Comment: @JordanTigani may help you on Resource exceeded, or place a ticket on Google enterprise support if you have access.